# NUnit System.BadImageFormatException When Running Unit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, teamcity

First let me preface this post by saying that I have seen various discussions on this topic within the TeamCity forums and here on SO, yet nothing seems to work for me.

I have a C#.Net solution and have configured two steps within TeamCity, a build step and a unit test step. When running the NUnit test I get the following error in TeamCity:

> [Step 2/2] Starting:
>   C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe
>   #TeamCityImplicit [Step 2/2] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\trunk [Step 2/2] 2013-02-23 18:00:11,827
>   [4972] WARN  JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.PE.PEReader - Failed to parse
>   assembly file: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is
>   [Step 2/2] System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable
>   (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid. [Step 2/2] at
>   Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\4fb4fc7600eac5a9\src\Utils\src\PE\ImageReader.cs:line
>   84 [Step 2/2] at
>   JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.PE.PEReader.DescribeAssemblyRuntime(String
>   assemblyFile) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\4fb4fc7600eac5a9\src\Utils\src\PE\PEReader.cs:line
>   22 [Step 2/2] Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner [Step 2/2] Running
>   NUnit-2.6.2 tests under .NET Framework v2.0 x64 [Step 2/2]
>   ##teamcity[buildStatus text='NUnit error, {build.status.text}' status='ERROR']   [Step 2/2] NUnit error running tests in
>   '...UnitTests.csproj' assembly   Loading assembly is compiled for
>   Failed to parse assembly file: Format of the executable (.exe) or
>   library (.dll) is invalid. NUnit runner runtime is v2.0.50727, x64
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '...UnitTests.csproj' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format. File name:
>   '....UnitTests.csproj' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not
>   load file or assembly '....UnitTests.csproj' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format. File name: '....UnitTests.csproj'

I am running TeamCity 7.1.4.  I am using Visual Studio 2012, and my current configuration is 64 bit.  I am using nunit 2.62 runtime version 2.0.

I have configured my TeamCity settings as follows:

MSBuild Step:
.NET Frameworrk 4.5
Run Platform: x64

NUnit Step:
NUnit Runner: 2.6.2
.NET Runtime: Platform x64
Version: v2.0

The unit tests all pass when run with resharper.

Knowing that BadImageFormatExceptions are usually related to compiling a 64 bit project in x86 or vice versa, I have tried just about every combination of 64/x86 settings for both my configuration manager for the solution, as well as the various settings within team city. It seems like regardless of my settings, I get this error.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` can also mean that you are attempting to load a file that is not a .Net assembly. The error message suggests that you are trying to load `UnitTests.csproj`, not an assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @adrianbanks on this one. Turns out I was pointing to the .csproj file to execute the tests. Per Adrian, I configured TeamCity to point to the unit test dll, and everything worked.